# How to develop Android Apps using a Samsumg Galaxy 5 device?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, device

I am developing my first Android App. I have an application already running on emulator (Eclipse + Android dev. tools) on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - the Lucid Lynx - released in April 2010. I have already tryied the [steps provided on Android Developers Portal](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) on this link, but whenever I try to list my already connected device using ./adb devices I get the following:

```
mmaia@mmaia-desktop:~/tools/android-sdk-linux_86/tools$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

I have checked and when I run the virtual emulator the same command returns:

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
emulator-5554   device
```

Also when I ask eclipse to run the emulator it finds the device(galaxy 5), see image below, but can't find serial, probably because of some permission, than I am only able to choose the virtual emulator.

[image]

How do I configure permission to use Galaxy 5 as a device while developing for Android under Ubuntu 10.04?

[]s

Comment: I have noticed when I do the connection that device asks for one USB conf. the options are: Kies or Storage. Is this relevant?

Comment: Just checked and looks like debugging mode only works under kies mode but I am Still stuck on the permission problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few ideas:

Make sure you not only created the udev rules, but also did

chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Use dmesg shortly after plugging in the phone to verify that it's enumerating nicely as a usb device.

See if you can get the adb shell up

Can you do a mass storage mount?  That's not a development function but would at least be a test that the usb is working.

Comment: Hi, it worked, thanks. In fact I got some sleep, than with fresh mind I just reviewed and.. It worked :) Thanks for helping.

Comment: Additionally, run lsusb to see if your device manufacturer is listed.

Answer (score 5):

Go the platform-tools directory in the Android SDK folder. From the terminal, type 'sudo ./adb kill-server'. This'll stop the adb server and now, restart it as the super user as 'sudo ./adb start-server'. Your device should be detectable now.

Comment: Just to mention, "./adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" works for me but when excuted as root (type sudo -s in terminal before typing previous commands).

Answer (score 1):

I have never done this before, but at a guess it could be your phone. Have you enabled the options for development?

You can do it by hitting the menu key when you are on the home screen, go to settings, then applications, and then development. If this isn't it, I will try to get mine working at reply again.

Comment: hi, yes I have already enabled the options for development. At least what is instructed by the link I provide in my question.

Comment: Have you enabled debugging in your AndroidManifest.xml file? It's in the applications tab of the file.

Comment: Hmmm. I have just gotten mine working (HTC Desire), but the Samsung Galaxy in work was showing up earlier. My last suggestion might be a stupid one, but double check that you have the right code in your "/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules" file.

    SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"

instead of

    SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

Comment: Just checked and it looks fine. I have tryied different combinations using usb,usb_device but still get the same "no permissions"

Comment: I will double check this with the Samsung Galaxy I have in work. I'll be there in 10 hours. Hopefully you will have the solution by then.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi, have just restarted Ubuntu e now looks like permission problem is gone, but still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

After restarting Ubuntu I have retried and now the error is a bit different. When I run adb devices I get:

```
mmaia@mmaia-desktop:~/tools/android-sdk-linux_86/tools$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    device
```

It looks like there is an id missing??
Than when I try from eclipse It gives the error:

```
[2010-10-07 21:32:56 - AnototudoAndroid] ------------------------------
[2010-10-07 21:32:56 - AnototudoAndroid] Android Launch!
[2010-10-07 21:32:56 - AnototudoAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2010-10-07 21:32:56 - AnototudoAndroid] Performing br.com.anototudo.MenuPrincipalActivity activity launch
[2010-10-07 21:32:56 - AnototudoAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2010-10-07 21:33:02 - AnototudoAndroid] WARNING: Unknown device API version!
[2010-10-07 21:33:02 - AnototudoAndroid] Uploading AnototudoAndroid.apk onto device '????????????'
[2010-10-07 21:33:02 - AnototudoAndroid] Failed to upload AnototudoAndroid.apk on device '????????????'
[2010-10-07 21:33:02 - AnototudoAndroid] java.io.IOException: device (????????????) request rejected: device not found
[2010-10-07 21:33:02 - AnototudoAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

[]s

Answer (score 0):

If the issue persists after doing the kill-server and sudo ./adb devices, then you prob have eclipse running in the background with the adk stuff. Exit it to enumerate devices properly

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal
Type '

> lsusb

'

You will get the list of USB drives connected to the system as shown below.

> Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04e8:681c Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd

copy the required USB info for further usage and then type below in the terminal again

> sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

You will get a notepad, paste the below line of code in that

> SUBSYSTEMS==”usb”, ATTRS{idVendor}==”04e8″, ATTRS{idProduct} ==”681c”,
>   MODE=”0600″

Modify the values of vendor and idProduct with the values of the 04e8:681c which we got from the lsusb command.

Save it and restart the adb server by using below commands.

Killing Server
adb kill-server or sudo ./adb kill-server

Start Server
adb start-server or sudo ./adb start-server

You will get connected to the device now.

Comment: All of these commands you must do like a root. Go to terminal and type:

sudo -s
After that type:

gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
and paste this text:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"

Type:

chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
After that (still as root) restart udev:

adb kill-server
adb start-server
Now try:

adb devices

Answer (score 0):

I have a galaxy 5 and I use as follow:

1. open the terminal and enter in your plataform-tooles folde

   ```
   $ cd /yourSdkDirectoryInstallation/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
   ```
2. as root kill and restart adb server:

   ```
   # ./adb kill-server && ./adb start-server
   ```

   or 
        `$ sudo ./adb kill-server && sudo ./adb start-server`